# Cassandra, counters and delete by field

Tags: database, cassandra, counter, cql

I've this specific use case. I'm storing counters in a table associated with a timestamp:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metrics(
  timestamp timestamp,
  value counter,
  PRIMARY KEY ((timestamp))
);
```

And I would like to delete all the metrics whose timestamp is lower than a specific value, for example:

```
DELETE FROM metrics WHERE timestamp < '2015-01-22 17:43:55-0800';
```

But this command is returning the following error:

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid operator < for PRIMARY KEY part timestamp"
```

How could I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 3):

For a delete to work, you will need to provide a precise key with an equals operator.  Deleting with a greater/less than operator does not work.  Basically, you would have to obtain a list of the timestamps that you want to delete, and iterate through them with a (Python?) script or short (Java/C#) program.

One possible solution (if you happen to know how long you want to keep the data for), would be to set a time to live (TTL) on the data.  On a table with counter columns, you cannot do it as a part of an `UPDATE` command.  The only option, is to set it when you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metrics(
  timestamp timestamp,
  value counter,
  PRIMARY KEY ((timestamp))
) WITH default_time_to_live=259200;
```

This will remove all data put into the table after 3 days (259200 seconds).

**EDIT**

And it turns out that the *possible* solution really isn't possible.  Even though Cassandra lets you create a counter table with a `default_time_to_live` set, it doesn't enforce it.

Back to my original paragraph, the only way to execute a `DELETE` is to provide the specific key that you are deleting.  And for counter tables, it looks like that is probably the only way possible.

Comment: this might work, but I'm stuck with this issue now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120834/cassandra-default-time-to-live-property-is-not-deleting-data